# Chrome still shows site as un-secure even after using valid SSL certificate

Tags: https, tomcat8.5

I have a webapp running on a Tomcat server. I changed the `server.xml` file by adding the following tag:

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
   maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSL"
   keystoreFile="path" keystorePass="password" />
```

Now when I go to the login page, I first get shown the **Your connection is not private** page and when I go to my page using the advanced settings, in the top left corner I still get **Not Secure**. When I click on the **Not Secure**, it shows certificate (invalid) but when I click on certificate it says it is valid. I am pretty sure that the certificate is valid. Any reason why it is showing **Not Secure**? The certificate has not expired as it also shows the expiry date of the certificate. I have implemented my app using Spring-MVC and Spring Security.[image: error page screenshot]